# How to install printenv from Nixpkgs?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

On Linux, I can use `printenv` to print shell environment variables.

However, when I [search](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=printenv) on Nix binary cache for `printenv` I get `No packages found`.

Is there a way to get that package via Nixpks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printenv` will be available if you install [coreutils](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.05&show=coreutils&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=coreutils) from Nixpkgs.

Comment: to just try out a package you can run `nix-shell -p coreutils` to open a shell with the package. For finding packages `nix-shell -p nix-index --run "nix-locate bin/printenv"`